# .NET Core: how to apply AddScoped from .NET 5 to .NET 6?

Tags: c#, database, .net-core

I'm currently using .NET 6, for the example I look upon using .NET 5 or below (?), so I don't know how to convert this code:

```
services.AddControllers();
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Service>, ServiceRepository>();
```

to this code

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceRepository, IRepository > ();
```

How to change the code?

Comment: @X i mean the opposite, how to put service from .net 5 to .net 6

Comment: The `service` in `IRepository<Service>` is  `IServiceCollection`? Do you wan to know how to get `IServiceCollection` in .net 6?

Comment: Or could you provide the link of the example you look upon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IRepository<T> and IRepository are two different interfaces, right? Why you have a different interface in the second example?

If you change the code of the second example, it should be like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository, ServiceRepository>();
```

Because here comes the interface first and then the implementation

```
IServiceCollection AddScoped<TService, [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors)] TImplementation>
```